# How to migrate a Django model into models with table inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Our current Django project has a model that already has a huge amount of instances in the database. When we started the project we had only one application in mind. Due to new requirements and planning for upcoming applications, we have realized that it might be very beneficial to restructure the database using model inheritance now before it's too late. This is because we can split this model (that has a lot of data in the database) into a base model and another one inheriting from it. The benefit of doing so is that the new applications of the project will also be able to inherit this base model as it contains common fields.

I know that this change would imply a table for the base model and other tables that are related to that table. I am wondering if there's a way that I can perform these changes while minimizing the impact of the data. Ideally, I would like to keep the id's intact, since customers are using the data already.

Since basically all the database is of `ModelA`, my idea was to convert all the data of this model into a model inheriting from a base model: `ModelA(BaseModel)` and then get the common fields that I want to be in the `BaseModel` out of ModelA. Then the subsequent models would all inherit from `BaseModel`.

I'm just not sure if this can be done of if I would have to make a command, for example, to get all the fields of the existing data and create new data for the new tables.

```py
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(...)
    field1 = models.ManyToManyField(...)
    field2 = models.TextField(...)
    field3 = models.TextField(...)
```

```py
class ModelA(BaseModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(...)
    field4 = models.ManyToManyField(...)
    field5 = models.TextField(...)
    field6 = models.TextField(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to restructure your database, you should export you data just to be safe.

When you eventually make the proposed changes, django will more likely interpret it as drop table and create table.